# Do you know some stats about Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

Does anyone have any neat statistics about Stack Overflow? I've been tracking (for the last 2.5 months):

- [The number of questions](http://webnumbr.com/stackoverflow-questions).
- And [the number of featured questions](http://webnumbr.com/stackoverflow-featured).

Questions are linearly growing, and featured are all over the place.

Anything else that you've been tracking? Or any other statistics on the site that would be good to track?

Comment: The linearity of that first graph is interesting. Stackoverflow's user base grows, but so does the answer database. Can it really be that these things balance out, thus resulting in a near constant questions/week rate? Seems remarkable to me.

Comment: The more users also means the increase in number of dups or 'close-able' posts. That's my deduction. Anyway, nice piece of stats work done by Paul. :)

Comment: Yeah, it was surprising to me too. Do you know a page that shows the # of answers that I can graph too? (Or just make the graph using webnumbr yourself)

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware that there is a [public data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)?  It is released once a month and a couple of use have setup sites, blogged about it, and posted graphs into questions & answers here on MSO.

Search for the tag [data-dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=data-dump&sort=votes&pagesize=50)

Comment: Great! You can clean lots of things once a month, but I like seeing the daily changes too. Like the plateaus over the weekend in my graphs. Is there an online version with stats on a webpage displaying hourly?

Comment: clean -> glean... yeah...

Comment: I've been aware of the weekend plateaus from the first dump in June.   And the hourly plateaus.  It is even possible to focus in on a single user's answering patterns.  A near-real-time stream it is not.  But the dumps are very, very detailed and easy to get interesting numbers from.