# Why are questions getting fewer and fewer views?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, views

I used to be able to ask a question on Stack Overflow and get 20+ views in about 2 minutes.

Now, I get less than 5 views in 2 hours.

Did something change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number to look at is the question age on the front page, which shows 48 questions.

Right now, the oldest question on the front page (at the bottom of the list) is 7 minutes old.

I have considered making this list dynamically larger as the site gets busier -- in other words, ensure that the range is at least 15 minutes -- but I'm not sure if people would actually scroll all the way down the page.

Comment: I would rather scroll then load a new page.

Comment: Some of us would scroll.

Comment: Why not the twitter-esque clicking the bottom horizontal bar to load more?

Comment: I totally wouldn't scroll. Unless I could *keep* scrolling, Google Reader-style, eventually reaching the very first question posted... at which point i would scratch my head wondering what "joel data" is and finally notice my bleeding eyes. So for the sake of those of us with compulsive personalities, please don't implement this cool idea.

Comment: I think that @GeorgeStocker's idea could be a very good addition. Have an expanding list of questions when the user requests it.

Answer (score 3):

There are many more users now in SO, and maybe even too many questions. Once your question moves to the 2nd page and subsequent pages, it will be less viewed, unless it's a good one, and people seek that exact knowledge.

Comment: That effect should be countered by having more users seeing the question at the same time.

Comment: Probably, but the real answer hides in the ratio between people that only asks question to people that actually seek to give answers. I Don't have the info, but I believe there are more of the first ones now.

Comment: @Dani, that's possible, haven't thought about that.

Comment: I think SO is attracting more casual users: first timers, most of which will only ask a few questions, answer fewer, and often lose interest. That's to be expected and part of the cost of remaining welcome to newcomers: they need to be able to *try* it, after all ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The question count ballooned much faster than number of users. For users who filter views by tags, more tags meant they are diluting your post's visibility; and like what Dani stated, your post get pushed off the front page much sooner than before.

Comment: Have any data about the question count versus number of answering users?

Comment: I don't have it off-hand, but the guys here are crazy over stats, you can post a question about it. The data dump might give you some info tho: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/do-you-know-some-stats-about-stackoverflow/27973#27973

Answer (score 2):

Could this be an issue with GMT? I am Indian, and I'll post at night to get replies quickly and often get a higher view count.

Comment: How much is many?

Comment: You 'post at night', but it's daytime *somewhere*. Maybe the largest group of SO users (is it in the US or India?) are awake to answer your questions.

Comment: That's why he asks them at night...

Comment: Undoubtedly US developers are more in SO