# Why do some questions just don't receive the attention others get?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I've asked a few question on Stack Overflow in the last few days, but unfortunately none of them were answered or even looked at.

They are well-written, reasonable and well researched questions about programming languages, yet nearly no one looked at them. That makes me wonder!

Why is it that some questions get a boost high into the sky, yet others are left behind? Why does it seem like some questions do receive the attention of the whole community, while others get barely a handful of views in *weeks*? What could be the possible reason behind this, and what can we do to change it?

Comment: Suggest moving to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I don't see any questions in your profile besides this one. Can you provide some links? Maybe they simply weren't good questions.

Comment: Looks like this is a new account specially for this question.

Comment: It's because people wants to give you the change of getting the `tumbleweed` badge.

Comment: I think the original question should just have been closed. It was just a very informal request without any significant work put into it.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: Yeah...but I wanted to get rid of that general tag...and while I was at it...

Answer (score 2):

There's two questions here.

First, the views.  People will read a question if it appeals to them.  This means that the title and tags should be descriptive.  Of course, if nobody knows anything about the language you are asking about, there's really nothing we can do about that.  There's a whole lot of .NET people here, for historical reasons, and there's usually a few around for every language I've heard of people using in the last two decades, but you might have hit one that nobody here knows.

Second, the answers.  Some questions are, simply, hard to answer, or really obscure.  In those cases, I'd generally prefer no answer to a wrong one.

Without knowing what questions you're referring to, I really can't say any more.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32127/why-are-questions-getting-less-and-less-views/32130#32130) showed this

**Jeff Atwood's answer:**

The number to look at is the question age on the front page, which shows 48 questions.

Right now, the oldest question on the front page (at the bottom of the list) is 7 minutes old.

I have considered making this list dynamically larger as the site gets busier -- in other words, ensure that the range is at least 15 minutes -- but I'm not sure if people would actually scroll all the way down the page.

Comment: it is no longer 48 questions. Try counting them..

Comment: @Jeff: 100? Do I get a price now? (or is it effectively dynamic now?)