# Use regular page sizes for questions on homepage

Tags: feature-request, homepage, pagination

On most pages displaying a list of questions or posts, users can choose the page size, which is either 15, 30 or 50:

[image]

That would lead many people to believe those page sizes are fixed, but it turns out the homepage is an exception: [recent science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383079/295232) confirmed the number of questions shown is 14 (for anonymous users) and 48 (for logged-in users). While [we've discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383079/how-can-i-download-the-full-front-page-of-an-se-site#comment1277640_383081) those numbers can be tied to [one of the most famous memes on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232), for consistency's sake, wouldn't it better to stick to the regular page sizes (15 resp. 50) instead?